# Im having trouble importing a the request module in Python

Tags: python, import, request, pip, installation

I wanted to use the request library for python and I went to windows powershell and put in 'pip install requests'and it said install successful but when I open up an ide it says that it cannot find the import when I try to use it. How do I use a python import installed with the pip command?

Comment: Make sure you installed requests into a location that your IDE can see.

Comment: Make sure you typed `import requests`, not `import request`

Answer (score 0):

suppose virtual environment issue

to check:
under powershell: pip show requests

notice the path it installed

under IDE, open the shell and type: pip show requests

it should show nothing if you inside the virtual environment.  then simply pip install requests again, and then pip show requests, you would see the requests module under your venv folder